# Add Dependency Property to existing .NET class

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

IN a WPF project I have a bunch of controls in which I would like to be able to set individual `Margin` properties and conserve the other values. So, I would like to avoid setting the complete margin to a new `Thickness` (`Margin="0,5,0,15"`). Because many margin's are set from styles etc. But in individual cases I would like to deviate from the generic styles for certain controls.

I thought, why not register a couple of new dependency properties on the .NET class `FrameWorkElement` like so (for example only MarginLeft is shown):

```
public class FrameWorkElementExtensions: FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarginLeftProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MarginLeft", typeof(Int16?), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnMarginLeftPropertyChanged));
    public Int16? MarginLeft
    {
        get { return (Int16?)GetValue(MarginLeftProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MarginLeftProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnMarginLeftPropertyChanged(object obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (obj != null && obj is UIElement)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)obj;

            element.Margin = new Thickness((Int16?)e.NewValue ?? 0, element.Margin.Top, element.Margin.Right, element.Margin.Bottom);
        }
    }
}
```

But this property doesn't come available in code-behind or in XAML. I can understand it somehow, because this dummy class is never instantiated or whatsoever. Tried to make it a static class but then you can't derive from FrameWorkElement (which I need for the GetValue and SetValue methods).

I couldn't find any resource on the net that treats the more generic question: Can you add dependency properties to exiting .NET classes?

Any help / wise advice is appreciated.

BTW: a solution for changing only one component of a Margin (Thickness) is also appreciated ;)

Comment: You might want to look into [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Comment: And especially into the [Custom Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx#custom) section.

Comment: Why was this down voted without saying why? Seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to define a property to be set on an object that you do not own then you want to define an attached property in which case you would use the [RegisterAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597497.aspx) method instead of Register. Also you would define the property as static get/set methods and not as an instance property since this would not be set on an instance of your object but on some unknown frameworkelement. The help topic from the link shows an example. The links in the other comments also provide more information and examples.

Comment: And where do I put the registration of this attached property so that all controls that derive from FrameworkElement can make use of it?

Comment: You can define it on any class - doesn't even have to be a dependency object. Of course when you want to set an attached property you have to reference the class that defines the property. So local:FrameworkElementExtensions.MarginLeft=20 for example where local is mapped to the clr namespace in which you defined it (e.g. if its in the local assembly and in the clr namespace foo then xmlns:local="clr-namespace:foo").

Comment: That being said this approach really isn't going to work well if you plan on setting the Margin property directly in addition to using your attached properties. I mean what if the xaml processor applies your property before the actual Margin property setting? You would have to watch when the Margin property changes and if you're not the one changing then re-insert your changes. Also if there is a binding on the Margin property you could end up removing/stepping on the binding (because your value will be a local value property precedence).

Comment: You *might* be able to use the DependsOnAttribute to affect the order of the props but I'm not sure how well that works. The last time I tried using that - pretty early on in WPF - it didn't do anything. The docs indicate it affects the order of the XamlWriter.Save.

Comment: This is not exactly what I need I have to conclude. I don't need an attached property so that I can do FrameworkElementExtensions.MarginLeft=20. I jst want each and every FrameWorkElement (and it's derived classes) to have MarginLeft available. And use it like: btnAdd.MarginLeft = 20, txtLabel.MarginLeft=15, etc.

Comment: But that isn't possible. Attached properties are the supported means for setting a DP on an object you don't own. Technically you could register a DP for an existing type as you originally had but there is lots of code that goes looking for the CLR get/set defined by that type and that simply will not exist for existing types. If this is about code then you could create an extension method so you could write something like btnAdd.SetMarginLeft(20) and in your extension method you could set the attached property. This won't help xaml though and there are no extension properties.

Answer (score -1):

If you want change only one component of a margin use in xaml Margin="1,2,3,4", where 1 - left, 2 - top, 3 - rigth, 4 - bottom

Comment: I know that off course...but I want to be able to set only the top margin for example without affecting other margins (left, right, bottom) that were set from a style somewhere else...

Comment: Nope...does that leave the other margins untouched?

Comment: Sorry, it does not work...maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657275/wpf-add-to-margin-without-overriding-existing-value