# WPF label styling

Tags: wpf, xaml, label, cornerradius

I have the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="WhiteStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">               
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>    
</Style>
```

However, I would like to add the property `CornerRadius` and modify the value. Unfortunately, the XAML error says a `Label` does not have a `CornerRadius` property. My question, How must I modify this XAML?

Thanks,

Comment: You would need to attach a Dependency Property to an existing control: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318707/add-dependency-property-to-existing-net-class .  I suggest applying this Style to `TargetType="{x:Type Border}"` and wrap Border around your Label.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is correct, you cannot set a corner radius on a Label.

What you can do is wrap the Label with a Border and apply your style to that to get the desired look.

**EDIT:**

The Style Resource:

```
<Style x:Key="MyBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
      <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
</Style>
```

The border wrapped label:

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource MyBorderStyle}">
    <Label Content="My Label" />
</Border>
```